# Can you upgrade Samsung Series 5 NT500R5LA notebook ram? if yes where is it exactly located? if no is there an ext ram slot? and where is the ext ram?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have been struggling to find answers with my laptop NT500R5LA ram replacement and if its soldered or not and if it has an external ram slot. I am not entirely sure as I learned from sources that some laptops task manager (performance) could be saying false information about the ram in task manager (performance).

So, I decided to open my laptop and tried to search for the ram but couldn't find the ram inside my laptop. In summary I am just trying to find information if my laptop NT500R5LA ram is replaceable or not. and if it is replaceable where is the ram located? if not is there an external ram slot inside the laptop and where is it located?

Information on my laptop just in case you need it:

```
NT500R5LA
S/N:0P0N91KJ900002
CPU: i5-6200U
RAM: 8gb
GPU: 940mx, intel HD graphic 520
DISK 1: LITEON CV3-8D128 (SSD)
DISK 2: WDC WD5000LPCX-35VHAT0 (HDD)
WIFI: Dual-band wireless-AC 8260
```

Comment: Quick google search for spec says memory is onboard, as in not in modules you can upgrade. I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 2):

This page  [icecat: Samsung 5 NT500R5LA Laptop](https://icecat.biz/en/p/samsung/nt500r5l-z77l/5-notebooks-nt500r5la-32849918.html) has a datasheet for your laptop.

The datasheet says

> Memory form factor: On-board

which suggests that it is soldered to the motherboard and not user upgradeable or replaceable.

That it specifically says `on-board` rather than `DIMM` shows that your memory may not be able to be upgraded.

Comment: sorry if there is a misunderstanding but my laptop is NT500R5LA-Z54R

Comment: @thisnut I didn't misunderstand anything. Your model is NT500R5LA and the "Z54R" could be a region code showing installed language. It is the same model as I linked with a slight variation and not likely to be wildly different.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to find the manual for your computer model on the internet
or on the Samsung website.

Searching
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/products/memory/laptop-dram)
for Samsung NT Series Notebooks, offers upgrades only for the
models of
91083K/93108K/91083P/91183K, NT801X5L-K201A and NT91083P.

I would conclude that your computer's memory cannot be upgraded.